# How to open an mbtiles file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector-tiles, mbtiles, tippecanoe

I am trying to open an `example.mbtiles` file in QGIS, but I cannot get it to work. Reproducible setup below.

---

### Create example input file

Using [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/index.html) and [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html), I create an `example.geojson` file:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

p = Polygon([(10,60),(11,60),(11,61),(10,60)])
gpd.GeoDataFrame({'geometry':[p]}).to_file('example.geojson')
```

Using [`tippecanoe`](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe), I create `example.mbtiles`:

```
tippecanoe --force -o example.mbtiles example.geojson
```

Output:

```
For layer 0, using name "example"
1 features, 36 bytes of geometry, 9 bytes of separate metadata, 0 bytes of string pool
  99.9%  14/8673/4720
```

Using [`mbview`](https://github.com/mapbox/mbview), I inspect the output:

```
mbview example.mbtiles
```

Output:

```
Listening on http://localhost:3000
```

on http://localhost:3000 I see:

[image]

a triangle, as expected.

---

### QGIS loading attempt

In the Vector Tiles page of QGIS, the ["Supported Formats" part](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector_tiles/vector_tiles_properties.html#supported-formats) says:

> There is support for vector tiles through:
>
> ...
>
> - local MBTiles database - e.g. `type=mbtiles&url=file:///path/to/file.mbtiles`

Relying on this, I find the full path of my file, create a string as in the example above:

```
type=mbtiles&url=file:///Users/palszabo/pal/colesbukta/example.mbtiles
```

add it to QGIS as a Vector Tiles Connection:

[image]

Instead of getting data on the map, I get:

[image]

ie

> Invalid Data Source:
> type=mbtiles&url=type%3Dmbtiles%26url%3Dfile:///Users/palszabo/pal/colesbukta/example.mbtiles&zmax=14&zmin=0
> is not a valid or recognized data source.

---

**How can I visualize `example.mbtiles` in QGIS?**

Comment: There might be a lot of things wrong in many places. Just a test, have you tried to simply drag and drop mbtiles into a QGIS map window?

Comment: Yes. It works! Thank you!